# The attachment file with email in PHP do not appear. Can someone help me?

Tags: php, html, html-email, email-attachments

### The attachment file with email in PHP do not appear. Can someone help me?

i just want to know why my attachment file in email using php cannot appear. i donno which part that i have error. i'm still new with coding. This is my php.

---

```
   <?php
  /// Message Vars
      $msg = '';
      $msgClass = '';

     $country_array = array("Afghanistan", "Aland Islands", "Albania", "Algeria", "American 
    Samoa", "Andorra", "Angola", "Anguilla", "Antarctica", "Antigua", "Argentina", "Armenia", 
    "Aruba", "Australia", "Austria", "Azerbaijan", "Bahamas", "Bahrain", "Bangladesh", "Barbados");

// Check For Submit
if (filter_has_var(INPUT_POST, 'submit')) {
    // Get Form Data
    $position = $_POST['position'];
    $fname = $_POST['fname'];
    $gender = $_POST['gender'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $phone_num = $_POST['phone_num'];
    $countries = $_POST['countries'];
    $salary = $_POST['salary'];

     // Check whether submitted data is not empty
    if (
        !empty($position) && !empty($fname) && !empty($gender) && !empty($email) && !empty($phone_num) && !empty($countries) && !empty($salary) 
    ) {
        // Passed
        // Check Email
        if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false) {
            // Failed
            $msg = 'Please use a valid email';
            $msgClass = 'alert-danger';
        } else {
            // Passed
            $from = 'sender@abc.com'; 
            $toEmail = 'shafikanizm@gmail.com';

            // Header for sender info
            $headers = "From: $fname"." <".$subject.">";

            // Email subject 
            $subject = 'Applying for Robotic Process Automated (RPA) Developer';  
             
            //plain text
            $body = "--$boundary\r\n";
            $body .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
            $body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n\r\n";
            $body .= chunk_split(base64_encode(
                
            'Name: ' . $fname . "\n" . 'Email: ' . $email . "\n" . 'Position: ' . $position . "\n" . 'Gender: ' . $gender  . "\n" . 'Phone Number: ' . $phone_num . "\n" . 'Country: ' . $countries . "\n" . 'Expected Salary: ' . $salary
            . "\r\n"
        )
    );          
                if (!empty($_FILES['attachment']['name'])) {
                    //read from the uploaded file & base64_encode content for the mail
                    //get file details we need
                    $file_tmp_name = $_FILES['attachment']['tmp_name'];
                    $file_name = $_FILES['attachment']['name'];
                    $file_size = $_FILES['attachment']['size'];
                    $file_type = $_FILES['attachment']['type'];
                    $file_error = $_FILES['attachment']['error'];
        
                    $handle = fopen($file_tmp_name, "r");
                    $content = fread($handle, $file_size);
                    fclose($handle);
                    $encoded_content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content));
        
                    //attachment
                    $body .= "--$boundary\r\n";
                    $body .= "Content-Type: $file_type; name=\"$file_name\"\r\n";
                    $body .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$file_name\"\r\n";
                    $body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
                    $body .= "X-Attachment-Id: " . uniqid('email_', true) . "\r\n\r\n";
                    $body .= $encoded_content;
                }

            // Send email
            $sentMailResult = mail($toEmail, $subject, $body, $message, $headers );

             // If Email sent
            if ($sentMailResult) {
                $msg = 'Thank you for filling up our form! Our team will be contacting you shortly.';
                $msgClass = 'alert-success';
                $_POST = array();
            } else {
                // Failed
                $msg = 'Your request was not sent';
                $msgClass = 'alert-danger';
            }
        }
    } else {
        // Failed
        $msg = 'Please fill in all fields!';
        $msgClass = 'alert-danger';
    }
}
?>
```

---

This is my html. I already try my best to do this attachment file with email in php. but still confusing :(

---

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">

  <body>
    <main id="main">
      <br><br>
      <div class="custom-section-title1" data-aos="fade-up">
        <h2>APPLY NOW</h2>
      </div>

      <!-- ======= Contact Section ======= -->
      <section id="contact" class="contact">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row justify-content-center" data-aos="fade-up">
            <div class="col-lg-7">
              <button id="x" style=" color: white;"><a href="job1.php"><i style="font-size:24px" class="fa">&#xf00d;</i></a></button>
              <div class="info-wrap"><br>
                <?php if ($msg != '') : ?>
                <div class="alert <?php echo $msgClass; ?>">
                  <?php echo $msg; ?>
                </div>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <h6 class="required">Position Applied For</h6>
                        <select class="form-select form-control" name="position" aria-label="Default select example">
                          <option value="rpa" selected="position">Robotic Process Automated (RPA) Developer</option>
                          <option value="prog">Analyst Programmer</option>
                        </select>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <h6 class="required">Name</h6>
                        <input type="text" name="fname" class="form-control" placeholder="Please fill your name">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <h6 class="required">Gender</h6>
                        <select class="form-select form-control" name="gender" aria-label="Default select example">
                          <option value="na" selected="gender">--Choose One--</option>
                          <option value="male">Male</option>
                          <option value="female">Female</option>
                        </select>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <h6 class="required">Contact No.</h6>
                        <input type="tel" class="form-control" id="phone" name="phone">
                        <!-- <span id="valid-msg" class="hide">✓ Valid</span> -->
                        <span id="error-msg" class="hide"></span>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <h6 class="required">Country</h6>
                        <select class="form-select form-control" name="countries" aria-label="Default select example">
                          <?php

                             foreach ($country_array as $value) {

                                                ?>
                            <option value="<?= $value ?>" title="<?= ($value) ?>">
                              <?= ($value) ?>
                            </option>
                            <?php

                                                }

                                                ?>
                        </select>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-7">
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <h6 class="required">Expected Salary</h6>
                        <input type="text" name="salary" class="form-control">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <h6 class="required">Email</h6>
                        <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" 
                   placeholder="Email Address">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="file">
                      <p>Upload Resume:</p>
                      <input type="file" name="attachment" class="form-control">
                </form>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Send Message" class="btn-contact">
                  </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                </form>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>

    </main>

  </body>

  </html>
```

---

What i am missing actually?

---

Comment: You can try to create a multi-part email manually, but as you just discovered, it is quite tricky. Most people use a library to do this, and the most used library is [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer). This might not solve all your email problems. It is getting harder and harder to get your email delivered and not be destroyed or end up in the spam folder. To solve this you could use an email service with an API to send email. They do all the hard work and you don't have to worry about it.

Answer (score 1):

Check with below code, add relative path for document.

```
function mail_attachment($files, $path, $mailto, $from_mail, $from_name, $replyto, $subject, $message, $cc, $bcc) 
    {
        $uid = md5(uniqid(time()));
        $header = "From: ".$from_name." <".$from_mail.">\r\n";
        $header .= "Reply-To: ".$replyto."\r\n";
        $header .= "cc : < $cc > \r\n" ;  // comma saparated emails
        $header .= "Bcc :  < $bcc >\r\n"; // comma saparated emails
        $header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
        $header .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$uid."\"\r\n\r\n";
        $header .= "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\r\n";
        $header .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
        $header .= "Content-type:text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
        $header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\n";
        $header .= $message."\r\n\r\n";
    
        foreach ($files as $filename) 
        { 
            $file = $path.$filename; // path should be document root path.
            $name = basename($file);
            $file_size = filesize($file);
            $handle = fopen($file, "r");
            $content = fread($handle, $file_size);
            fclose($handle);
            $content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content));
    
            $header .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
            $header .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"".$filename."\"\r\n"; // use different content types here
            $header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
            $header .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$filename."\"\r\n\r\n";
            $header .= $content."\r\n\r\n";
        }
        $header .= "--".$uid."--";
        return mail($mailto, $subject, "", $header);
    }
```